# Unable to generate *.g.dart files for flutter plugin

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-plugin

I have created a flutter plugin and that is using native SDKs for iOS and Android. I have integrated this plugin into my flutter app.
I am able to access the plugin when I want to trigger some methods already written in plugin. Then I am facing errors.

Here is error snippet:

```
Failed to build iOS app
Error (Xcode): ../../.pub-cache/git/private_sync-465gf982e539d46aa60e874355147f05c5039231/lib/sync_client.dart:6:6: Error: Error when reading '../../.pub-cache/git/private_sync-465gf982e539d46aa60e874355147f05c5039231/lib/sync_client.g.dart': No such file or directory
```

Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 14 Pro Max.